# Null Values in ProcedureCall

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures, parameters

I try the following code:

```
    ProcedureCall call = ss.createStoredProcedureCall("servicos.CLASSIFIER_MAP");

    call.registerParameter( 1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(classifierString);
    call.registerParameter( 2, Long.class, ParameterMode.IN ).bindValue(totalRows);
```

Sometimes the variable totalRows is null and an error appears

```
WARN:   SQL Error: 17041, SQLState: 99999
Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
```

It is possible to send null values into a ProcedureCall in hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try calling your stored procedure via `CallableStatement` instead of `ProcedureCall`.

And try and leverage its `setNull` method to set procedure IN parameters as NULL.

But for your answer whether hibernate supports passing NULL value, it seem to support default parameter values over substituting a null value.

Comment: Ok. But do you know how can I use a CallableStatement with a StatelessSession from hibernate API?

Comment: This post might help you with example of how to achieve with CallableStatement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045641/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-null-parameter-to-a-stored-procedure-in-java-jpa-2-1

Comment: Hibernate's API getSession().doWork() is where you need to override the execute method

Answer (score 11):

Currently there are 2 ways to achieve your objective :

1. Set the property `param_null_passing` to true in your hibernate configuration. 
   `<property name="hibernate.proc.param_null_passing">true</property>` 
   This is a global setting which will enable you to pass null values in to `ProcedureCall` throughout your application.
2. If you do not wish to apply the above setting globally, change your code to the following :

   ```
   ProcedureCall call = ss.createStoredProcedureCall("servicos.CLASSIFIER_MAP");

   call.registerParameter( 1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(classifierString); 
   call.registerParameter( 2, Long.class, ParameterMode.IN ).enablePassingNulls(true);

   call.setParameter(2,  totalRows);
   ```

From the Hibernate 5 [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html) :

hibernate.proc.param_null_passing (default value is false) :

> Global setting for whether null parameter bindings should be passed to database procedure/function calls as part of ProcedureCall handling. Implicitly Hibernate will not pass the null, the intention being to allow any default argument values to be applied.
>
> This defines a global setting, which can then be controlled per parameter via org.hibernate.procedure.ParameterRegistration#enablePassingNulls(boolean)
>
> Values are true (pass the NULLs) or false (do not pass the NULLs).